# Use of indexOf() Method in JavaScript

Tags: jscript.net

```
var araj=["1","2"];  
var idx=Array.IndexOf(araj,"1");
```

Doesn't work as expected. Why, and what's next?

EDIT: it is javascript in asp.net (so the friend who won't open account here says)

Comment: And what results are you getting?

Comment: What language is this? C#? VB? JavaScript?

Comment: have you tried `araj.IndexOf("1");` ?

Comment: Why is this ASP now? It was Javascript a second ago

Comment: Guys, sorry, it's jscript in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive language. `IndexOf` should be `indexOf`:

```
var araj=["1","2"];  
var idx=Array.indexOf(araj,"1");
```

**Result:**

```
0
```

**More Info:**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_indexof.htm

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` has a lowercase **i**

Answer (score 1):

Change `IndexOf` to `indexOf`.

> Javascript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Although equivalent, I prefer this method.

```
var araj = ['1', '2'];
var idx = araj.indexOf('1');
alert(idx);
```